# identifying a dir from a filelist

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I can get the list of files at a path, but I cannot remove all the directories from the list

```
    fileList = [[myFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDir,  appDelegate.user_name] error:&theError] 
retain];



NSLog(@"FileList: %@", fileList);

for (int i =0; i< [fileList count]; i++)
{
    NSString *fileName = [fileList objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([fileName hasSuffix:@"dir"])
    {
        NSLog(@"dir found");
        [fileList removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        i--;
    }
}
```

I'm obviously misunderstanding how to execute this, can anybody advise me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (NSString *path in fileList) {

  BOOL isDir = NO;
  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir]) {

    if(isDir){
        //...
    }
  }
}
```

from the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> ```
> - (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>   *path*   The path of a file or directory. If path begins with a tilde (~), it must first be expanded with stringByExpandingTildeInPath, or
>   this method will return NO.
>
> *isDirectory*   Upon return, contains YES if path is a directory or if the final path element is a symbolic link that points to a directory,
>   otherwise contains NO. If path doesn’t exist, the return value is
>   undefined. Pass NULL if you do not need this information.